# "peer authentication failed" error while loading data into PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu, psql, pg-restore

I was trying to load a data file `dvdrental.tar` into a database `dvdrental` in PostgreSQL.

Error:

```
pg_restore: [archiver (db)] connection to database "dvdrental" failed: FATAL:  Peer authentication failed for user "postgres"
```

The command I ran:

```
$ cd /usr/lib/postgresql/10/bin
$ pg_restore -U postgres -d dvdrental /home/pranav/Documents/DVDRentalDB/dvdrental.tar -W
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two options:

1. run the command as operating system user `postgres`.
2. Change the authentication method to something else than `peer` in the `pg_hba.conf` file and reload PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I've configured my `/etc/postgresql/12/main/pg_hba.conf` the next way:

```
# This file controls: which hosts are allowed to connect, how clients
# are authenticated, which PostgreSQL user names they can use, which
# databases they can access.  Records take one of these forms:
#
# local      DATABASE  USER  METHOD  [OPTIONS]
# host       DATABASE  USER  ADDRESS  METHOD  [OPTIONS]
# hostssl    DATABASE  USER  ADDRESS  METHOD  [OPTIONS]
# hostnossl  DATABASE  USER  ADDRESS  METHOD  [OPTIONS]
hostssl      dvdrental,flights,demo all  192.168.1.5/24 trust
hostssl      dvdrental,flights,demo all  128.131.232.29/32 trust
host all all 192.168.1.0/24 md5
local all postgres peer
```

I'm not expert in postgres configuration, but was looking for the same in case of following [this guide](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/load-postgresql-sample-database/), but using ubuntu as an OS.

After that I've restarted postgre services:

```
sudo systemctl restart postgresql*
```

And then I was able to execute the next command without authentication errors:

```
sudo -u postgres pg_restore -c -U postgres -d dvdrental -v /tmp/dvdrental.tar -W
```

As you can see, I've copied `dvdrental.tar` file to `/tmp` directory, so it could be used by `postgres` user, which could not have access to your `/home/youruser` directories. It is better to not play with directories permissions. Better copy desired files to `/tmp` folder and use them from there.